# Which free open source CPanel and WHM alternatives do you recommend/use?

Tags: linux, hosting, web-hosting

I have been using webmin for some time now, however I miss the elegance and ease of WHM/CPanel combo I've had on shared hosting (and later dedicated hosting) platform.

Looking around the web, all I have found that is somewhat at the level of WHM/CPanel was webmin - but WHM/CPanel it is not.

Since I'm using this only for our projects, it doesn't matter in the end really. However, we do put our new customers on our servers too, so some sort of CPanel might be an easier thing for them to cope with (mostly going about Email accounts stuff and such).

Currently my stack is LAMP (CentOS and Ubuntu Server - several machines, probably ditching CentOS soon in favor of Ubuntu). There is a prospect of Python/Django instead of PHP, but it might take awhile.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://www.anchor.com.au/hosting/development/we_hate_plesk_and_cpanel

If you need pretty front-ends for customer use, pick the best-of-breed ones for each individual task.  Postfixadmin, for instance, for mail user use.  They'll make far less of a mess of your system than any of the horrendous "all in one" control panels will, and allow you to keep administering the system properly, providing full flexibility to do what needs to be done.

Comment: +1 After using WHM/cPanel for a long time, that thing becomes more of an obstacle than a helpful thing. Many times when I need to change/tune something I realize that that will affect WHM/cPanel in some way.

Answer (score 4):

[ebox](http://ebox-platform.com/) has been adopted by Ubuntu as the official config platform for ubuntu server. It has (I belive) a higher level view of tasks than webmin - task based rather than config file based.

On ubuntu hardy (8.04 LTS) it can be installed from the repositories, though apparently it is a bit broken in the gutsy and intrepid releases. [More on ebox in ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/eBox).

Comment: ok, although ebox is not what I am after, it looks interesting for other things, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here are 12 Cpanel Alternatives

```
Virtualmin

ISPConfig 3

Web CP

Flex CP

SysCP

Ehcp

Zpanel

Kloxo

OpenPanel

Website Panel

ServerPilot
```

If you're on a tight budget, then you should see if you can factor in the low cost of directadmin. Many believe this the best control panel alternative to cpanel which doesn't break the bank.

And I would suggest ISPConfig 3 and Zpanel. It's a complete and well tested solution which is used by many smaller hosters.

> http://www.ispconfig.org/ispconfig-3/

Answer (score 2):

While http://webmin.com may not have everything you desire you can always go for the paid version http://virtualmin.com

I definitely agree with the link to "we hate plesk and cpanel".

It doesn't sound like you've had any admin problems with cPanel so are not as jaded.

The main thing I like about webmin/virtualmin (if you have to have an administrative interface other than the command line) is that if you do decide to remove it or do things from the Command Line Interface then it's not going to trash your system.

Comment: AFAIK - virtualmin is not a paid solution

Answer (score 0):

With my current host I have [Parallels](http://www.parallels.com/) Plesk Panel. I like it a lot. But I have never used any of the alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

I currently host 3 websites that get decent amounts of transfer but I currently have 2 corporate website offers that need something more reliable and stable.
[whm-cpanel.eu.pn](http://whm-cpanel.eu.pn/)